# How to strip port number from http request url?

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite, httpd

I am using httpd server for load balancing and as web server.
I want to convert my request from : http://hostname:port/service to http://hostname/service 
How it can be done using RewriteRule or any other technique ?

Comment: Please add your attempts and any issue or error you encountered trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `:port` comes from the URI scheme ([RFC 3986, 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)) Syntax Components:

> ```
>      foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
>      \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
>       |           |            |            |        |
>    scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
> ```
>
> [**3.2.3.  Port**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3)
>
> The port subcomponent of authority is designated by an optional
> port    number in decimal following the host and delimited from it by
> a    single colon (`:`) character.
>
> ```
>   port        = *DIGIT
> ```
>
> A scheme may define a default port.  For example, the `http` scheme
> defines a default port of `80`, corresponding to its reserved TCP
> port number.  The type of port designated by the port number (e.g.,
> TCP, UDP, SCTP) is defined by the URI scheme.  URI producers and
> normalizers should omit the port component and its ":" delimiter if
> port is empty or if its value would be the same as that of the
> scheme's default.

Therefore,

- `http://example.com` equals ONLY `http://example.com:80`
- `https://example.com` equals ONLY `https://example.com:443`
- for any other port the port is visible in the URL.

If you have a web service e.g. on `http://example.com:8080/service` and you would like to use a different web server (e.g. as a load balancer) on `http://example.com/service`, you'd need a ***reverse proxy*** on the web server listening on port `80`. In Apache it's done with module [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html):

```
<Location "/service">
  ProxyPass "http://example.com:8080/service"
</Location>
```